# How can I align multiple audio files with overlapping using python?

Tags: audio, speech, time

I need to align multiple audio files with different overlapping regions. Is there a python/command line library that does so?

Comment: can you use something else than python? because you can make pretty nice scripts using ffmpeg ?

Comment: yes i can @jonhatan smith

Answer (score 1):

You're not gonna like this. The only for-sure way of lining up audio files is to have them All the same length to begin with, including the silences. So when you record them, make sure you start from zero with each file, even if it only has one bleep five minutes in! Lining up varying length soundfles is a nightmare otherwise.

Yours respectfully

Chris

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he was asking [not sure *what* the question really is]... but it's sound advice for stems in any case ;)

Comment: there are work that uses time-frequency constellation analysis to determine  overlap between recordings. I need to align them to use multi channel signal enhancement using beamforming. @ulrichburke